# How to render button similarly in Safari and Chrome?

Tags: css, safari, vertical-alignment

Considering the next code:

```css
.test {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  background: initial;
  font-size: 11px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.test::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<button class="test">Some Text Content</button>
```

In Chrome it's rendered like (hot it is required):
[image]

In Safari it's rendered like:
[image]

So, in Safari it's not vertically centered and the block has different size.

**The main question is how to center it vertically in Safari?**

The secondary question is how to make blocks absolutely similar?

*I tried `display: flex; align-items: center;`, `vertical-align: center;`, changing line-height – nothing from that seemed to work...*

Comment: I've faced this issue too and because of different rendering engines, personally I rather to reduce the `height` and add some `padding-top` to it and manually align the text where  ever I want. By this trick you can be sure that even in oldest versions of browser your button looks the same!

Comment: @MohsenNemati Thanks for your comment, but adding height and padding-top would certainly affect rendering in other browsers when it's rendered normally.

Comment: I can't see a problem if you **delete** the align codes (like `vertical-align`) and use padding-top instead. How can this cause any problems?

Comment: @MohsenNemati The problem with that is that I have another element in the button (an Icon) besides the text. So, if I set padding-top for the button, both elements move down (which is undesirable). If I wrap the text with a container and set padding-top to this container, it gets ok in Safari, but not ok in e.g. Chrome. So,  in this case, with setting padding-top checking what browser is required, but there is no guarantee that this problem appears only in Safari – it's just one case I'm working on right now... Probably, will implement this overtop checking in case won't find another solution.

Comment: sounds like you have to make sure your icons and text have the same height.

Comment: @ravb79 The container are of the same height and the text has the same line-height as its container.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean, but regardless, the proper value for `vertical-align` is `middle`, not center.

Answer (score 0):

```
.btn {
border:1px solid #000;
box-sizing:border-box;
color:#000;
display:inline-block;
font:1rem/1.5 sans-serif;
height:2rem;
padding:0 1rem;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
width:auto;
}
```